# sql order by most matched record

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote sql query to match any word in keyword. now i want to order it most matched word.
how can i do that.

here is my sql query.

```
select a.itemId, a.tags from items a
where a.quantity <> 0 and a.deleted <> 1 and a.tags rlike replace("master guide grade 10", ' ', '|')
```

For example if there is record **"master guide grade 10"** it comes first then if there is record **"master guide grade 6"**  like so i want to get result set. how can i do that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can look for each value separately and add together the matches:

```
select a.itemId, a.tags
from items a
where a.quantity <> 0 and
      a.deleted <> 1 and
      a.tags rlike replace('master guide grade 10', ' ', '|')
order by (a.tags like '%master%') + (a.tags like '%guide%') + (a.tags like '%grade%') + (a.tags like '%10%') desc
```